# getParcelableArrayListExtra returns arraylist with boolean false as second object

Tags: android, android-intent, parcel

I wish I could have given this question a bounty right away, I've been held back by this issue for over a day.

The situation is a little bit complex:

I'm trying to send an ArrayList from one activity to another using intent's extras. If I debug the code straight after putting it in the intent, it seems to be OK:

[image: in intent]

If you look at the watches you can see that the intent is correctly filled.

If the ArrayList only contains 1 object, everything works out, but not if it contains more than 1 object. I then get the following error:

```
   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@2133e0d8: Unmarshalling unknown type code 6619168 at offset 392
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2032)
            at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2235)
            at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1655)
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1986)
            at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226)
            at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
            at android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Bundle.java:1217)
            at android.content.Intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.java:4798)
            at nl.raakict.android.spc.SearchMapActivity.onCreate(SearchMapActivity.java:85)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5267)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I added the code of the object (and the sibbling objects). Note that there is a catchy bit in this to, I also have an abstract class which implements Parcellable:

class OrderLine:

```
package nl.raakict.android.spc.Model;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import nl.raakict.android.spc.Interface.RenewOrderLinesListener;
import nl.raakict.android.spc.Interface.onApiCompleteListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class OrderLine extends BaseModel implements onApiCompleteListener, Parcelable {

    private int ID;
    private int OrderID;
    private String Order_Number;
    private String PartName;
    private String Materiaal;
    private double Thickness;
    private double XSize;
    private double YSize;
    private int Amount;
    private String ImagePath;
    private String PositionNumber;
    private double Weight;
    private String Remark;
    private String BonNumber;
    private int ParentOrderLineID;
    private String ParentAssemblyName;
    private String Barcode;
    private ArrayList<OrderLineOperation> OrderLineOperations;
    private ArrayList<OrderLineLocation> ActiveOrderLineLocations;
    private String StatusColor;
    private boolean Completed;
    private long LocationID;
    private int CustomerID;
    private String CustomerName;
    private OrderLineOperation CurrentOperation;
    private boolean IsTransportReady;
    private String PlanningLocation;
    private transient RenewOrderLinesListener apiCompleteListener;

    public OrderLine(){
        ActiveOrderLineLocations = new ArrayList<OrderLineLocation>();
    }


 // Getters, setters, derived methods of onApiCompleteListener



    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(getID());
        dest.writeString(getPartName());
        dest.writeInt(OrderID);
        dest.writeString(Order_Number);
        if(ActiveOrderLineLocations == null || ActiveOrderLineLocations.isEmpty())
            dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
        else {
            dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
            dest.writeTypedList(ActiveOrderLineLocations);
        }
    }

    public OrderLine(Parcel in) {
        this();
        ID = in.readInt();
        PartName = in.readString();
        OrderID = in.readInt();
        Order_Number = in.readString();
        if(in.readByte() == (byte)1)
            in.readTypedList(ActiveOrderLineLocations, OrderLineLocation.CREATOR);
    }

    /**
     * * This field is needed for Android to be able to * create new objects, individually or as arrays. * * This also means that you can use use the default * constructor to create the object and use another * method to hyrdate it as necessary. * * I just find it easier to use the constructor. * It makes sense for the way my brain thinks ;-) *
     */
    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public OrderLine createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new OrderLine(in);
        }

        public OrderLine[] newArray(int size) {
            return new OrderLine[size];
        }
    };

    public ArrayList<OrderLineLocation> getActiveOrderLineLocations() {
        return ActiveOrderLineLocations;
    }

    public void setActiveOrderLineLocations(ArrayList<OrderLineLocation> activeOrderLineLocations) {
        ActiveOrderLineLocations = activeOrderLineLocations;
    }
}
```

class OrderLineLocation:

```
package nl.raakict.android.spc.Model;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class OrderLineLocation extends BaseModel implements Parcelable {

private int ID;
private OrderLine OrderLine;
private int OrderLineID;
private int CurrentAmount;
private LocationBase Location;
private String DateChanged;
private long UserID;
private boolean Archive;
private boolean IsOnStockLocation;
private String SupplierID;
private long LocationID;


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(this.ID);
    if (this.OrderLine != null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
        dest.writeParcelable(this.OrderLine, 0);
    } else
        dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
    if (this.Location != null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
        dest.writeParcelable(this.Location, 0);
    } else
        dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
    if (this.Location != null)
        dest.writeInt(this.OrderLineID);
    dest.writeInt(this.CurrentAmount);
    dest.writeString(this.DateChanged);
    dest.writeLong(this.UserID);
    dest.writeByte(Archive ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
    dest.writeByte(IsOnStockLocation ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
    dest.writeString(this.SupplierID);
}

public OrderLineLocation() {
}

private OrderLineLocation(Parcel in) {
    this.ID = in.readInt();
    if (in.readByte() == (byte) 1)
        this.OrderLine = in.readParcelable(nl.raakict.android.spc.Model.OrderLine.class.getClassLoader());
    if (in.readByte() == (byte) 1)
        this.Location = in.readParcelable(nl.raakict.android.spc.Model.LocationBase.class.getClassLoader());
    this.OrderLineID = in.readInt();
    this.CurrentAmount = in.readInt();
    this.DateChanged = in.readString();
    this.UserID = in.readLong();
    this.Archive = in.readByte() != (byte) 0;
    this.IsOnStockLocation = in.readByte() != (byte) 0;
    this.SupplierID = in.readString();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<OrderLineLocation> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<OrderLineLocation>() {
    public OrderLineLocation createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new OrderLineLocation(source);
    }

    public OrderLineLocation[] newArray(int size) {
        return new OrderLineLocation[size];
    }
};
```

}

class LocationBase (the abstract class):

```
package nl.raakict.android.spc.Model;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class LocationBase extends BaseModel implements Parcelable {

    protected String __type;
    protected long Id;
    protected String Name;
    protected String Barcode;
    protected String Remark;
    protected int Discriminator;
    protected int AmountOfSegments;
    protected ArrayList<Carrier> Carriers;
    protected ArrayList<OrderLineLocation> OrderLineLocations;
    protected ArrayList<Order_Header> Orders;
    protected LocationBase Location;
    protected ArrayList<OrderLineLocation> ActiveLocations;



    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.__type);
        dest.writeLong(this.Id);
        dest.writeString(this.Name);
        dest.writeString(this.Barcode);
        dest.writeString(this.Remark);
        dest.writeInt(this.Discriminator);
        dest.writeInt(this.AmountOfSegments);
        if(this.ActiveLocations == null || this.ActiveLocations.isEmpty())
            dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
        else {
            dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
            dest.writeTypedList(this.ActiveLocations);
        }
        if(this.Orders == null || this.Orders.isEmpty())
            dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
        else {
            dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
            dest.writeTypedList(this.Orders);
        }
    }

    public LocationBase() {
    }


    public static final Parcelable.Creator<LocationBase> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<LocationBase>() {
        public LocationBase createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            Byte b = source.readByte();
            if(b == 0)
                return nl.raakict.android.spc.Model.Carrier.CREATOR.createFromParcel(source);
            else
                return nl.raakict.android.spc.Model.Location.CREATOR.createFromParcel(source);
        }

        public LocationBase[] newArray(int size) {
            return new LocationBase[size];
        }
    };
}
```

And Carrier (implements the LocationBase abstract class)

```
package nl.raakict.android.spc.Model;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Carrier extends LocationBase {

    private int LocationID;
    private int CarrierTypeID;
    private boolean CanBePlacedOnCarrier;
    private boolean CanBeCarrierLocation;
    protected int StartSegment;
    private String CarrierTypeName;
    private int NumberOfEdges;
    private transient int Indentation;


    public Carrier() {
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
        super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
        if (this.Location != null) {
            dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
            dest.writeParcelable(this.Location, 0);
        } else
            dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
    }

    protected Carrier(Parcel in) {
        this.__type = in.readString();
        this.Id = in.readLong();
        this.Name = in.readString();
        this.Barcode = in.readString();
        this.Remark = in.readString();
        this.Discriminator = in.readInt();
        this.AmountOfSegments = in.readInt();
        if(in.readByte() == (byte)1)
            in.readTypedList(ActiveLocations, OrderLineLocation.CREATOR);
        if(in.readByte() == (byte)1)
            in.readTypedList(Orders, Order_Header.CREATOR);
        if (in.readByte() == (byte) 1)
            this.Location = in.readParcelable(nl.raakict.android.spc.Model.LocationBase.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<LocationBase> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<LocationBase>() {
        public Carrier createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Carrier(in);
        }

        public Carrier[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Carrier[size];
        }
    };

}
```

Lastly the class Location

```
package nl.raakict.android.spc.Model;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Location extends LocationBase  {

    protected int LocationGroupID;
    protected int PositionZ;

    public Location() {
    }

    protected Location(Parcel in) {
        this.__type = in.readString();
        this.Id = in.readLong();
        this.Name = in.readString();
        this.Barcode = in.readString();
        this.Remark = in.readString();
        this.Discriminator = in.readInt();
        this.AmountOfSegments = in.readInt();
        if(in.readByte() == (byte)1)
            in.readTypedList(ActiveLocations, OrderLineLocation.CREATOR);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
        super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<LocationBase> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<LocationBase>() {
        public Location createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Location(source);
        }

        public Location[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Location[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `OrderLineLocation.writeToParcel`, `OrderLineID` gets written only if `Location != null`.
However, when reading in `OrderLineLocation(Parcel in)`, there is always a `readInt()` call for `OrderLineID`, without condition, so that could cause an offset mismatch between the read and the write sequence.

Comment: You are right, I just found that error as well. Now I get a BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling "at nl.raakict.android.spc.Model.OrderLineLocation.<init>(OrderLineLocation.java:137)" which is "this.Location = in.readParcelable(nl.raakict.android.spc.Model.LocationBase.class.getClassLoader());" any ideas?

Comment: Though I have doubts about this but - have you tried passing null as a parameter to the 'readParcelable()' calls? That should make it fall back to the default class loader, which is what you probably want.

Comment: Well I do need the correct ClassLoader actually. I changed it to this:

parcel in 

if(in.readByte() == 1)
            this.Location = in.readParcelable(Carrier.class.getClassLoader());
        else
            this.Location = in.readParcelable(Location.class.getClassLoader());

writeToParcel:

dest.writeByte((byte) (this.Location instanceof Carrier ? 1 : 0));
        dest.writeParcelable(this.Location, 0);

no luck

Answer (score 0):

You have to much null verification to handle `List<?>`s and `Parcelable`s just to avoid null references. I suggest you ignore this and whatever if it is null, put it in `Parcel`.

Comment: That was all created after this error, even without I get the same result